# GeoServer 2.17.1 WAR running on Tomcat 9 not finding GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR context param

Tags: tomcat, geoserver

I have GeoServer 2.17.1 installed as a WAR servlet in Tomcat 9. If the data files are located in

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data

everything works correctly. However, If the data files are located in

C:\Users\geoserveruser\Documents\GeoServerData

and the following context-param is added to

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\web.xml

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR</param-name>
   <param-value>C:\Users\geoserveruser\Documents\GeoServerData</param-value>
</context-param>
```

the data directory is not found. In fact a new directory is created in

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data

when Tomcat is restarted. The GeoServer documentation

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/setting.html#web-archive

indicates this is the correct way to configure the GeoServer data directory and the context param is provided in web.xml and just needs to be uncommented and edited.

Why is this not working as indicated in the documentation?

UPDATE:
Found these in the Tomcat log file

```
29 Jun 16:35:17 WARN [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to C:\Users\geoserveruser\Documents\GeoServerData , but this path does not exist

29 Jun 16:35:17 INFO [geoserver.platform] - Falling back to embedded data directory: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data
```

This explains why a new data directory is being created.

C:\Users\geoserveruser\Documents\GeoServerData

definitely exists and I verified the current (and all users) have read-write permissions for the directory.

Thoughts?

Comment: please don't cross post the same question here and at [GIS.se](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366331/geoserver-2-17-1-war-running-on-tomcat-9-not-finding-geoserver-data-dir-context) - in this case gis.se is a much better place for it

Answer (score 0):

This is because `\` are not a very good character to use as a path separator in the Java world since they are used as the escape character. So if you must use a `\` it is necessary to use two of them to escape the escapiness of them so your path becomes `C:\\Users\\geoserveruser\\Documents\\GeoServerData` but better and easier is to move into line with the rest of the computing world and use `/` as a path separator giving `C:/Users/geoserveruser/Documents/GeoServerData`.

To be honest if you are going to the trouble of installing Tomcat this is probably going to be a production machine in which case you should probably rethink the whole windows idea and use a proper operating system which doesn't need to use 50%+ of the CPU virus scanning on every request instead.